# One accumulation point but no limit point, all members of sequence in $\mathbb R$ are different.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Give an example of a sequence in $\mathbb R$; such that  all its members are different numbers, it has only one accumulation point, but it does not have a limit

Answer (score 0):

How about $1, 2, \dfrac13, 4, \dfrac15, 6, \dfrac17, 8, \dfrac19, ...?$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=1/n$ when $n$ is even, $a_n=n$ when $n$ is odd. This clearly doesn't converge, but $0$ is the only accumulation point.